# C#, post, redirect and Back Button

Tags: c#, viewstate, redirect

There's a weird behavior where I use a post and then make a redirect to another page.
Then, if the user press the Back Button of his browser, the browser make a GET instead of a POST, so I lose the "viewstate". Why is the browser not "reposting" (or asking to repost) the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined by Wikipedia, PRG is “Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) is a common design pattern for web developers to help avoid certain duplicate form submissions and allow user agents to behave more intuitively with bookmarks and the refresh button.”

If you are interested in viewing the viewstate data of the POST request, before GET happens, then try using this utility: http://blog.getglimpse.com/2011/11/01/glimpse-0-86-released/

Comment: I see. It could cause weird behavior if not well implemented (as I experienced)